# Angular 2 dragulaModel throws Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined exception

Tags: ng2-dragula

I am using ng2-dragula and with data binding in 2 tables.  When a td is drag and drop to another table, it throws the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined. and is not able to drop the element.  Need help on how to resolve this problem.

Below is the html part

```html
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="text-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>Task ID</th>
                <th>Ref #</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Doc Type</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody [dragula]='"team-bag"' [dragulaModel]="tasks">
            <tr *ngFor="let t of tasks">
                <td>{{t.id}}</td>
                <td>{{t.refNbr}}</td>
                <td>{{t.custName}}</td>
                <td>{{t.docType}}</td>
                <td>{{t.receiveDate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
        <table class="table">
        <thead class="text-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>Task ID</th>
                <th>Ref #</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Doc Type</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody [dragula]='"team-bag"' [dragulaModel]="agentATasks">
            <tr *ngFor="let t of agentATasks">
                <td>{{t.id}}</td>
                <td>{{t.refNbr}}</td>
                <td>{{t.custName}}</td>
                <td>{{t.docType}}</td>
                <td>{{t.receiveDate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

tasks and agentATasks are both defined and populated in the component.ts.

Below is the error in Chrome console.
Subscriber.ts:241 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/ng2-dragula/components/dragula.provider.js:94:28)
    at emitter (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/contra/emitter.js:47:72)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/contra/emitter.js:46:10)
    at Object.thing.emit (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/contra/emitter.js:38:48)
    at drop (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/dragula/dragula.js:261:13)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.release (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/dragula/dragula.js:245:7)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5967:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:264:40)

Comment: Did you get any solution, I am getting the same error

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue. Using copy= true which works fine when dragulaModel is not set.

Comment: Any fix you got for this, I m trying to use same in mine Angular5 app, getting the same error, however, following the same way what they have mentioned in there doc... wondering how it is working for them.